# Play/Pause Animated Vector Drawable is not working?

Tags: android, animation, vector, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to create a Animated Vector Drawable from [here](https://codepen.io/mistkaes/pen/WvPrJL). But i can see only the play icon in the screen. If i click on the play icon it shows the pause icon at some other distance.

I hope that both the paths are compatible! According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727819/youtube-play-pause-animated-vector-drawable-on-android)

I don't know where i am going wrong ?

**Animated Vector**

```
<animated-vector
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_play"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <target
        android:animation="@animator/play_to_pause"
        android:name="play"/>
    </animated-vector>
```

**Vector Drawable**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="240.0dp"
    android:height="240.0dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:name="play"
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M 11 10 L 17 10 L 17 26 L 11 26 M 20 10 L 26 10 L 26 26 L 20 26" />
</vector>
```

**Object Animator**

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="100"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_cubic"
            android:repeatMode="reverse"
            android:repeatCount="1"
            android:propertyName="pathData"
            android:valueType="pathType"
            android:valueTo="M11,10 L17,10 17,26 11,26 M20,10 L26,10 26,26 20,26"
            android:valueFrom="M11,10 L18,13.74 18,22.28 11,26 M18,13.74 L26,18 26,18 18,22.28"
            />
    </set>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "If i click on it it shows the pause icon at some other distance." ?

Comment: @LewisMcGeary If i click on the play icon it shows the pause icon at some other distance. It is not transforming to pause icon!

Comment: @LewisMcGeary Any Suggestions ?